# How fast is this naive prime factorization algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm looking to figure out the big-o complexity of this code:

```
prime_factorize(N) {

   for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
       while (N % i == 0) {
           print i
           N = N / i
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't actually a programming language -- It's just pseudocode.

I know what the pseudocode is doing. It is dividing out all the factors of  2, then 3, etc. I also know that the code can be optimized to only go up to `sqrt(N)`, but I want to figure out the runtime of the code as I posted it.

While it is tempting to say the runtime is quadratic, I am pretty sure that's wrong. The reason why I think it's wrong is because I know that the prime sieve algorithm runs in `O(nloglogn)` time, and it sort of resembles this algorithm.

Can someone please help me analyze this algorithm?

Comment: `O(N)` worst case (when `N` is prime), `log(N)` best case (when `N` is power of `2`)

Comment: How do you get that?

Comment: When N is prime, it has no factors other than 1 and N. So your loop will count up all the way to N. That's N steps, hence O(N).

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: So this algorithm runs in `O(N)` time where `N` is the inputted number we want to factorize. What about if we input the number as an `n`-digit binary number (note the lowercase `n` rather than uppercase `N`)? Then if I want to write how fast my algorithm is in big-oh notation, I think it's `O(log(n))`. Is that right?

Comment: If the number written in binary has `n` digits (not counting leading zeros), then the value of the number is between `2^(n-1)` and `(2^n) - 1`. Which is to say that `N` is between `2^(n-1)` and `(2^n) - 1`. And since the algorithm is O(N) worst case, it is O(2^n) worst case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see that this algorithm runs in O(n) in worst case.

You just need to consider the case where n is a prime number, then `i` would iterate all the way until N.

The same thing occurs if N is not prime. Take N = 2 * 53 as example. It would take 53 iterations = O(N/2) = O(N).